# Why can a double clicked batch file not find a registry value for deletion?

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I wrote a bat file to delete an registry entry.

```
reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v VALUE /f
```

When I execute in cmd, it works.

But when I execute it by double click, it doesn't!!!

Error message:

```
Error: the system could not find the specified registry keys or values
```

Anyone else can tell me why!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On 64-bit Windows there is for automatic start of 64-bit applications

*HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run*

and for automatic start of 32-bit applications

*HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\**Wow6432Node**\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run*

If the batch file is executed by 32-bit **cmd.exe** in directory **%SystemRoot%\System32\** being automatically redirected for 32-bit applications to **%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\**, the registry path

*HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run*

is automatically redirected to

*HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\**Wow6432Node**\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run*

If the batch file is executed by 64-bit **cmd.exe** in directory **%SystemRoot%\System32\**, which can be called by 32-bit applications on Windows x64 using redirector **%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\** instead of **%SystemRoot%\System32\**, the registry path

*HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run*

is indeed referencing

*HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run*

So I suppose that `VALUE` exists in **Run** key for 32-bit applications (below Wow6432Node), but the batch file on double click is executed by 64-bit **cmd.exe** because 64-bit Windows Explorer is used. Therefore the value cannot be found in **Run** key for 64-bit applications.

The solution is to use

```
%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\reg.exe delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v VALUE /f
```

Please note that special redirector **%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\** exists only on 64-bit Windows and only for 32-bit applications, but does not exist on 32-bit Windows. Take that into consideration if the batch file should work also for 32-bit Windows.

For more information about redirections on Windows x64 read the Microsoft documentation pages:

- [Registry Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-redirector)
- [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run the batch file with elevated privileges. (Right click, "Run as Administrator")

It probably works in the command prompt because it is running itself with elevated privileges. For instance the command prompt shortcut might have its properties set to automatically run as an administrator.

Comment: I have try this right click [Run as Administraor].Still can't work.

Comment: Is there more than those 2 lines to your bat file? Are you executing from a network drive?

Comment: No, just in my local computer.