# What is the reason for different value after reg add from within a C# application and query the value from within a cmd window?

Tags: c#, cmd, registry, addition

I have a program coded in C# that opens a cmd console and adds/modifies a registry value.

After the console outputs that the task completed, I test with `reg query` if the registry value really changed. There is no problem. I get value `0x1` as expected by me.

But when I query this registry from outside the current cmd window like another cmd executed by me as admin, the value is `0x0` on `reg query`.

How is this possible?

Here is my C# code:

```
string command = @"/K reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock /t REG_DWORD /f /v AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense /d 1";

        Process proc = Process.Start("cmd.exe", command);
```

Query from inside the executed cmd by the program:

```
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock
    AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense    REG_DWORD    0x1
```

From outside:

```
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock
    AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense    REG_DWORD    0x0
    AllowAllTrustedApps    REG_DWORD    0x0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock\AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock\AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense=1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a 32-bit application on a 64-bit Windows accesses the registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock
```

it is redirected by Windows [registry redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-redirector) to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock
```

whereby a 64-bit application really accesses

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock
```

The difference between the two registry paths is `Wow6432Node` visible by default only for 64-bit applications on Windows x64.

See the Microsoft developer article [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys).

And for completeness see also:

- [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector)
- [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details)

There are 32-bit `cmd.exe` and `reg.exe` **on 64-bit Windows** in directory `%SystemRoot%\SysWow64` being `%SystemRoot%\System32` for 32-bit applications and 64-bit `cmd.exe` and `reg.exe` in `%SystemRoot%\System32`.

Your C# application is most likely compiled as 32-bit application and therefore calls 32-bit `cmd.exe` which calls 32-bit `reg.exe`.

You could workaround this from within the 32-bit application by calling explicitly `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\cmd.exe`.

But be aware of the fact that `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative` does not exist on 32-bit Windows and also does not exist for 64-bit applications on 64-bit Windows. (`Sysnative` is a special alias, not a hard link, junction or a real folder.)

Therefore your 32-bit C# application needs first to check if `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\cmd.exe` exists and use this path to edit the 64-bit registry value using 64-bit `cmd` and `reg`. But on 32-bit Windows `%SystemRoot%\System32.exe\cmd.exe` must be called by the 32-bit C# application. By the way: `%SystemRoot%` references the value of environment variable **SystemRoot**.

See also the answers on:

- [Why can a double clicked batch file not find a registry value for deletion?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27244524/3074564)
- [Changing value of registry key with getRuntime().exec(cmd) does not change registry value even the operation ended successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36822794/3074564) (Java, but same issue)

**NOTE 1:**

Running `cmd.exe` is not needed at all. It is possible to run directly on 32-bit Windows

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe
```

or on 64-bit Windows

```
%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\reg.exe
```

from a 32-bit application.

**NOTE 2:**

And last but not least a C# application does not need to use `reg.exe` at all as .NET Framework has built-in support for accessing Windows registry - the [Registry.SetValue Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry.setvalue). Microsoft even added some examples in an example code block.

**KEY_WOW64_64KEY** can be used in a 32-bit application to explicitly access always the 64-bit registry key as explained on Microsoft documentation page [Accessing an Alternate Registry View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/accessing-an-alternate-registry-view).

Comment: I tried the Registry.SetValue but when I execute the code it just don't work and never show an error... So... I changed from x32 to x64. Thank You!
(One little question, if the user have a x32 could I use this code changing again to x32?)

Comment: If the C# application is executed with a user account with no permissions to write to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` the method `Registry.SetValue`throws the `SecurityException` which of course must be caught by your C# application to handle the error on denied write access. Your C# code 32-bit compiled to an x86 application for Windows x86 works the same as 64-bit compiled to an x64 application.